# 3-Sliced Square

Tags: geometry

I remember this one time when my brother told me "with just 3 lines, how many shapes can you form in a square piece of paper?"

After 30 minutes, my 7-year-old brain thought that I could only make 5. However, my brother told me "no, you can make seven. " My brain exploded right there.

Now, with my 13-year-old brain, I now know that you can cut it to more than 7 times.

Now, it is your turn to do so. Cut the square with 3 lines, and say how many shapes you have generated (any type of polygon: hexagon, octagon, nonagon, square, triangle).

Hint 1:

> Use loopholes and anything possible that you can exploit!

Hint 2:

> What defines a line? Math isn't the only subject in the world!

Comment: The reason you've gotten downvotes is because the point of the question is "using loopholes". This means that the puzzle is very subjective, and perhaps better described as an exercise in creativity. Here on Puzzling, we prefer puzzles to have a single definitive answer that everyone will agree on -- so this type of question may not really be appropriate here.

Comment: The main problem with this question is that it's a puzzle that does not have a correct answer. Here, the only rule is "you can bend any rules", so it's entirely a popularity contest along the lines of "who can think of an entertaining way to do this". The site policy is that if you post a puzzle, there should be a correct solution, and it should be possible to tell a correct solution from an incorrect one without referring to OP. I wholeheartedly agree with you that downvoting without a comment is a crappy thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Not sarcastic, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I've interpreted the question correctly, but if so the answer is

> as many as I want, at least if we assume that paper is infinitely thin and infinitely finely divisible.

So, first of all, what I *think* the question is asking: Take a square. Make three cuts in it. What's the largest number of polygonal pieces you can end up with?

And apparently we are explicitly supposed to exploit any loopholes we can find. So here are two loopholes. First:

> A "line" is not necessarily a *straight* line. So make a zig-zagging line from, say, the middle of one side to the middle of the opposite side. Keep the two pieces in place. and now make another zig-zagging line "out of phase" with the first, crossing over the first line many times. We will get lots of little squarish pieces where the lines cross. We can get as many as we like. (Do what you please with the third cut.)

Second:

> The question doesn't explicitly disallow folding the paper. So, concertina-fold it many times parallel to one pair of sides, then do the same parallel to the other pair of sides. You end up with a much smaller square. (In practice it will also be much thicker, and may be difficult to cut.) Now cut across the middle of this parallel to each set of folds. (Again, we only need two cuts; do what you like with the third.) Each cut on the folded paper corresponds to many parallel cuts on the original square, which we thereby divide into a large number of rectangles.